# Präposition bei „lernen” und „kennen”. Aus oder von?

Tags: preposition

Grüezi,

Ich hätte eine Frage bezüglich der Verben **lernen** und **kennen** und zwar, ich will sagen, dass mir ein bestimmtes Wort irgendwoher bekannt ist. Wie heißt es dann:

*Ich lernte das Wort **aus/von** dieser Webseite.
Ich kenne das Wort **aus/von** dem Lehrbuch.*

Da wäre auch meine Bitte, eine möglichst allgemeine Regel aufzustellen, die zwischen beiden Präpositionen unterscheidet, falls ja überhaupt möglich.
Eine kenne ich grundsätzlich schon (**aus** bei *in* und *zu*, **von** bei den anderen Präpositionen), aber es klingt mir in diesem Fall unnatürlich.

Danke im Voraus

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe das Wort auf dieser Webseite (kennen)gelernt. - Ich würde hier "kennenlernen" verwenden.

Ich kenne das Wort aus dem Lehrbuch.

Die Präpositionen hängen von der Sache/Person, dem Verb und der Beziehung zwischen den beiden ab:

Ich kenne das Wort aus dem Lehrbuch. Ich kenne den Mann über einen Freund. Ich kenne das Wort durch ein Versehen. Ich kenne es nur für meinen nächsten Test. Ich kenne das Wort von der Website. etc.

Comment: Kennenlernen würde ich vor allem für Personen verwenden. Ein Wort kennenlernen klingt irgendwie komisch für meine Ohren. Ich kenne das Wort von der Website ist ansonsten auch verwendbar.

Comment: Kennenlernen würde ich auch nie in diesem Kontext benutzen. Es scheint also, dass die von mir genannte Regel doch auch in diesem Fall gültig bleibt - man sagt auf der Website -> von, im Lehrbuch steht dies und jenes -> aus.

Answer (score -1):

I think both of these are valid, but there is a distinction *w.r.t.* tempus. *I.e.* while you *know* the word currently, you *learned* it in the past. When creating a sentence with both of these, the following sentences will be considered correct by a native speaker:

1) *Ich habe das Wort von/auf dieser Webseite gelernt.*

2) *Ich kenne das Wort von dieser Webseite.*

Two notes on this: The second sentence is likely to be considered more colloquial, but also more common, personally I am likely to use 2). The other noteworthy detail is my usage of *auf*. it is akin to the distinction:

*I learned this word from that website* vs. *I learned this word on that website*. A native speaker is, in my opinion, more likely to use *auf* in this situation. However *auf* is not at all applicable in 2) - at least in this context.

Comment: *Von* der Website gelernt ist meines Erachtens falsch. Man lernt *von* Personen.

Comment: @Ludi You might be right there. As mentioned, I would have preferred *auf*. One could argue, the essence of *lernen von* is that a person is actively being taught - which a website may be able to provide. But reference to persons is indeed the common case.

Comment: Good point. I could indeed imagine this to become common, if websites were to be considered essentially personified teachers. At present, I feel, it sounds very weird.